# Which API endpoint will allow me to lookup user info by the Slack @tag

Tags: tags, slack-api

I'm creating a bot that reacts to `/command @userTag`. I can see Slack posting the event data of the user who typed `/command @userTag` and that the text submitted is `@userTag`.

I cannot figure out how to fetch user info by `@userTag`?

Answer (score 0):

The api used for fetching user info is : 
 **https://api.slack.com/methods/users.info**

You'll need to pass tagged user's **userId** along with the authentication token.

 This information will be available in the payload of the slash command.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, this doesn't quite address my issue. when `/command @userTag` is executed I get the user who is sending the message user ID but I do not get the tagged users information. That means I need to search via `@userTag` or find some other way to get their information.

Comment: if you can translate the **@tag** to **'emailId'**, then you can use following method : https://api.slack.com/methods/users.lookupByEmail . For example @lastname.firstname => lastname.firstname@domain.com . This may vary for different organizations.

Comment: Other option is to fetch the complete list of users using : https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list and then filter results.

Comment: I very much appreciate the time you took here. The full user list is the closest request I've come to being able to filter by tag. I really just need to easily get the tagged users name. Do you now if any other mechanism to do this other than tag when a user is typing a command?